# How do I make a VTK program launch in a maximized window?

Tags: c++, vtk

In VTK, I'm aware of making a "full-screen" window as well as adjusting the window size:

```
renderWindow->SetSize(1200,800);
renderWindow->SetFullScreen(true);
```

However, I want to get the application to start in a maximized window. I've searched high and low but cannot find any information on how to do this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
renderWindow->SetSize(renderWindow->GetScreenSize());
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I was having some trouble with that solution, but I'll try it again when I'm back at work on Monday.